# How to root Acer Z630s?

Tags: rooting

I'm trying to root my new phone, it's an [Acer Liquid Z630s](http://www.gsmarena.com/acer_liquid_z630s-7529.php) (T04) running Android 5.1.

I can't find anything useful online, Google is filled with auto-generated pages that just give a link to some one-click-root app. I've tried a couple of them (Kingroot, Kingoroot and OneClickRoot) and they all say "no root available at this time".

Comment: Try "Baidu Root". That one might work! :)

Comment: @RyanNoles I can't really find the download page and the sites linked on their [main page](http://baiduroot.net/) don't load. Do you happen to have a link?